# Handling null and exception from Java API call in Scala

Tags: java, scala, exception, scalaz

I have the following code (simplified):

```
def getSomething(name: String): MyError \/ Option[Int] = {
    /* Returns Null if name doesn't exist, IOException if connection err. */
    val output: queryDB(name)

    // ...
}
```

The `queryDB` function is a Java call.

I would like the following to happen: `IOException` mapped to `MyError`, and `null` to `None`. How should I proceed?

I am aware that I can wrap the output in an `Option` since `null` is mapped to `None`. However, how do I manage the exception?

Thanks.

Comment: anything wrong with try / catch? you could use `scala.util.Try` too, ie `Try( Option( queryDB(name) ) )` but old-school try / catch might just be simpler here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a combination of `Option` and `Try`

```
import scala.util.{ Try, Success, Failure }

def getSomething(name: String): MyError \/ Option[Int] = {

   Try(queryDB(name)) match {
     case Success(v) => Option(v).right // in case v is null, this returns a None
     case Failure(e) => MyError().left
   }

}
```

This turns all exceptions into `MyError`. If you need specific error handling you can match on `e` and have more granularity.

Also I'm using `.right` and `.left` that come from the `syntax` package of scalaz. If you are not using those, you can replace them with `\/-(Option(v))` and `-\/(MyError())` respectively.

Comment: `"If you need specific error handling you can match on e and have more granularity."` Does this mean to look at `Throwable`'s `getMessage`?

Comment: No, I mean matching on the exception type

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a combination of Either and Try. Using "transform" method of Try, you can convert the result to an Either[Throwable, Option[Int]]. Something along the lines of,

```
// Change the 2nd arg of transform to MyError as per your requirement.

def getSomething(name: String): Either[Throwable, Option[Int]] = {
    Try(queryDB(name)).transform(s => Success(Right(Option(s))), f => Success(Left(f))).get
}
```